# I want put flutter widget in one line after shrink

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, widget, formatter

I have a problem
in first image I shrinked Padding widgets and I can't select one without expanding it, it take too much time to select one.

[image: first image]

I wanna shrink the widget with open & close brackets in the same line like second image .....
[image]